# desktop GUI tool to browse and install new jars to the local maven repo

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

It would be even better if the same standalone tool can also support browsing repositories over other protocols than file system

Comment: I am not aware of one. It doesn't sound to hard though, have you tried writing one for yourself? And if you really want GUI, you could always use your OS's file browser by just navigating into your ~/.m2/repository directory.

Comment: I've seen a desktop gui couple of weeks back but I've forgot to bookmark the link. I've posted it in SO hoping someone might know about that tool. Unfortunately not the case :-(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this simple tool which is great

http://code.google.com/p/mycila/wiki/MavenDeployer

Answer (score 2):

The small tool maven-install-ui (https://github.com/escv/maven-install-ui) offers a simple UI to install jar files locally.

Answer (score 1):

Well, NetBeans comes at least with a local Maven repository browser, but I think it currently doesn't have a GUI to install new jars

Comment: I am aware of this too but as you mentioned it doesn't have the GUI for what I want to do and even if it does, I am looking for a lighter version

Comment: You can actually install jars to your local repository with Netbeans Maven support. If you declare a dependency to a maven artefact in your project it will appear as an icon in the list of project dependencies. Right-click on the icon and you have the option to install a local jar file.

Answer (score 1):

why not use the atifactory . You can install new jars from web UI